# How to fetch Google Drive PDF url using pdf.js script on new web page?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, drive, pdf.js

I have an example of two websites that uses google drive and whenever they have a new document they just change unique id (drive uploaded document) in URL (after ?id=) and than the documentis display in on a canvas. It's also SEO friendly and indexed by google. So what should be it's raw code?

- Demo - [Click Here | I want this One](https://www.highonstudy.com/category/pdf.php?id=1_YYynxvRPojY5QzshsjcI0Fi8-MwW0yX&name=BEL%20Recruitment%202020%20Notification) {Check Code by Inspect Tool}
- [Demo Website Image/Inspect code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9d8Kb.jpg)

I just want to use google drive for storage and call document on my website's pdf.js canvas for increase page view, user time, and display ads on PDF web pages like the demo that above.

Comment: You can embed the PDFs via iframe, how you are trying to implement that on webpage using npm or direct?

Comment: No, didn't want to show iframe directly like <iframe src="Drive URL" />. Also does not want to use NPM. Can you elaborate more on direct implementation? @xenon

Comment: As you said that you need on PDF.js then it will load everything on <canvas>, you can add the ads on the top in the same HTML. I can give the solution

Comment: Yes, let me know the solution.r

Comment: Let me know if that answer worked

Comment: Hi @xenon, It's working but I want to use the google drive file URL to preview at var url  = 'Drive File SOURCE URL'

Comment: you can, just get the URL from the drive and replace it. make sure that URL is in public view

Answer (score 3):

Here are is the demo for PDF.JS showing PDF in the webpage

```js
var url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mozilla/pdf.js/ba2edeae/web/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf'; //Loaading the PDF from URL

// Loaded via <script> tag, create shortcut to access PDF.js exports.
var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];

// The workerSrc property shall be specified.
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';

var pdfDoc = null,
    pageNum = 1,
    pageRendering = false,
    pageNumPending = null,
    scale = 0.8,
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

/**
 * Get page info from document, resize canvas accordingly, and render page.
 * @param num Page number.
 */
function renderPage(num) {
  pageRendering = true;
  // Using promise to fetch the page
  pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function(page) {
    var viewport = page.getViewport({scale: scale});
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;

    // Render PDF page into canvas context
    var renderContext = {
      canvasContext: ctx,
      viewport: viewport
    };
    var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);

    // Wait for rendering to finish
    renderTask.promise.then(function() {
      pageRendering = false;
      if (pageNumPending !== null) {
        // New page rendering is pending
        renderPage(pageNumPending);
        pageNumPending = null;
      }
    });
  });

  // Update page counters
  document.getElementById('page_num').textContent = num;
}

/**
 * If another page rendering in progress, waits until the rendering is
 * finised. Otherwise, executes rendering immediately.
 */
function queueRenderPage(num) {
  if (pageRendering) {
    pageNumPending = num;
  } else {
    renderPage(num);
  }
}

/**
 * Displays previous page.
 */
function onPrevPage() {
  if (pageNum <= 1) {
    return;
  }
  pageNum--;
  queueRenderPage(pageNum);
}
document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener('click', onPrevPage);

/**
 * Displays next page.
 */
function onNextPage() {
  if (pageNum >= pdfDoc.numPages) {
    return;
  }
  pageNum++;
  queueRenderPage(pageNum);
}
document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', onNextPage);

/**
 * Asynchronously downloads PDF.
 */
pdfjsLib.getDocument(url).promise.then(function(pdfDoc_) {
  pdfDoc = pdfDoc_;
  document.getElementById('page_count').textContent = pdfDoc.numPages;

  // Initial/first page rendering
  renderPage(pageNum);
});
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
button{
  border: none;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>

<h1>PDF.js Example</h1>

<div>
  <button id="prev">Previous</button>
  <button id="next">Next</button>
  &nbsp; &nbsp;
  <span>Page: <span id="page_num"></span> / <span id="page_count"></span></span>
</div>

<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

> For more details and documentation visit:

https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/

Answer (score 0):

Changed pdf URLs to see the result

Tested here:
https://codepen.io/max-makhrov/pen/JjpLxXP

Here're failed URLs:

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MUgtKfMqpyTtTFt2hEff23Emcg14Cj4O
https://drive.google.com/1MUgtKfMqpyTtTFt2hEff23Emcg14Cj4O/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf
https://drive.google.com/export?id=1MUgtKfMqpyTtTFt2hEff23Emcg14Cj4O
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1MUgtKfMqpyTtTFt2hEff23Emcg14Cj4O&exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&format=pdf&id=1MUgtKfMqpyTtTFt2hEff23Emcg14Cj4O
https://drive.google.com/uc?export?format=pdf&id=1MUgtKfMqpyTtTFt2hEff23Emcg14Cj4O
https://docs.google.com/viewer?srcid=1MUgtKfMqpyTtTFt2hEff23Emcg14Cj4O&pid=explorer&efh=false&a=v&chrome=false&embedded=true
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MUgtKfMqpyTtTFt2hEff23Emcg14Cj4O/
https://drive.google.com/file/export?format=pdf&id=1MUgtKfMqpyTtTFt2hEff23Emcg14Cj4O
```

Here's a surprise: you may use a range from existing Google Sheet if it has an Access. This URL works:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qNQ6iCMoBCQgJzBB63ymtBQ6BedXZFhjgZZKGItjeVA/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf&size=1.87x1.386&portrait=true&scale=2&top_margin=0&bottom_margin=0&left_margin=0&right_margin=0&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&horizontal_alignment=LEFT&gridlines=false&fmcmd=12&gid=0&r1=1&r2=7&c1=1&c2=4
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a demo to load pdf with lazy load. We need to implement drive api to fetch the pdf from drive or it will give cross-origin error.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PDF Demo for Qdev</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@2.2.228/build/pdf.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            background-color: #dfdfdf; /* Grey background */
        }
        .center {
            text-align: center; /* center pages */
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="pages" class="center"></div>
      <script>
        // download the pdf
        var pdfTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument("https://atikur-rabbi.github.io/data/sample.pdf");
        // parse the get params
        var queryString = window.location.hash.split("#")[1];
        // default params
        var params = {pg: 1};
        var pagen = 0;
        // if get params are present
        if (queryString) {
            // update the default settings
            params = Object.assign(params, parseParams(queryString));
        }
        // Load the pages div from the DOM
        var pages = document.getElementById("pages");
        // handle the pdf once loaded (asyncronous)
        pdfTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
            // globalize pdf
            window.pdf = pdf;
            // load the first page
            loadPage(pdf, parseInt(params.pg));
            pagen++;
        });
        // stores the page number of the page currently in the viewport
        var curpage = parseInt(params.pg) + pagen;
        // every half a second, check for scroll updates
        setInterval(function() {
            // if we're within 200px of the bottom of the page
            if (document.body.scrollHeight - (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight) < 200) {
                if (window.pdf != undefined) {
                    // load 5 more pages
                    for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
                        loadPage(pdf, parseInt(params.pg)+pagen);
                        pagen++;
                    }
                }
            }
            // if the page in our viewport has changed, update the url
            if (curpage != parseInt(params.pg) + parseInt(window.scrollY /
                    (document.body.scrollHeight / pagen))) {
                curpage = parseInt(params.pg) + parseInt(window.scrollY /
                    (document.body.scrollHeight / pagen));
                window.location.hash = "#pg=" + curpage;
            }
        }, 500);

        // render `pg` from `pdf` and append it to the pages div
        function loadPage(pdf, pg){
            pdf.getPage(pg).then(function(page){
                var scale = 1.7;
                var viewport = page.getViewport({scale: scale});
                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

                canvas.id = "page-" + pg;
                canvas.height += viewport.height;
                canvas.width = viewport.width;

                pages.appendChild(canvas);

                var renderContext = {
                    canvasContext: context,
                    viewport: viewport
                };
                page.render(renderContext);
            });
        }

        // parses get params from a query string into an object
        function parseParams(queryString) {
            var query = {};
            var pairs = (queryString[0] === '?' ? queryString.substr(1) : queryString).split('&');
            for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
                var pair = pairs[i].split('=');
                query[decodeURIComponent(pair[0])] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1] || '');
            }
            return query;
        }
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```